# Existence of constant such that there exists graph $G$ on $3n$ vertices satisfying certain properties

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Let $\alpha(G)$ denote the independence number of a graph $G$. Prove that there is an absolute positive constant $C$ such that for any $n\geq 1$ there is a graph $G$ on $3n$ vertices satisfying $\alpha (G) \leq C\log_{2}{n}, \alpha (G^2) \leq C(\log_{2}{n})^2,$ and $\alpha(G^3) \geq n$. (We define graph products here by the **strong product**.)

I'm thinking that a way to tackling this problem is to construct a graph $G$ that satisfies those properties for general $n$ and find a bound for the $C$ to set as the absolute constant, but I'm not sure how to begin with constructing such graphs in the general case.

Comment: If there are $n$ independent vertices in $G^3$, arent those vertices also independent in $G$ contradicting your claim of the result ? i.e,, if $\alpha(G^3) \geq n \implies \alpha(G) \geq n$ This is assuming the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power

Comment: Most likely this is one of the definitions of graph product in which $G^3$ has $(3n)^3$ vertices, but this underscores the importance of defining your terms in a question!

Comment: @Balajisb Thank you for pointing this out to me. I've edited the question to include that we are using the strong product as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs